# Custom view bitmap doesn't have correct size

Tags: android, view, bitmap

I want to load a bitmap with a certain size in a custom view. As a first step I wanted to load a 400px x 400px bitmap in a 400px x 400px view... but the bitmap is loaded with a smaller size.

I found some threads with similar issues. It was adviced to use `Options.inScale = false`. I used it, and got better log messages (bitmap outputs correct size 400px x 400px), but it still is rendered smaller:

[image]

(yellow is the background of the custom view - 400px x 400px, and red is the bitmap).

Any advices? Here is the code:

Custom view:

```
class TestView extends View {
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();

    public TestView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.overlay, options).copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);  
        Log.d("test6", "width: " + bitmap.getWidth() + " height: " + bitmap.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    >
    <com.example.TestView
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="400px"
        android:layout_height="400px"
        android:background="#ffff00"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The bitmap is already 400px x 400px ... that's why I think I don't have to use scaling options, etc. I just want to show it with this size in the screen...

Comment: Why are you creating the canvas in the constructor?  You're drawing the bitmap onto itself?  That's just odd, even if its not the bug-  you can remove all of that.

Comment: You're right - this is a part of a more complex example, I simplified it for this post... but part of the code is still there. Removed it.

Comment: What folder do you have the bitmap in?  Unscaled bitmaps should be `drawable-nodpi` folder.  Else, the system will sometimes scale it even though that bit is set regardless of the documentation.

Comment: I created a project using your source code (just without the options, I used null instead), and created a 400px by 400px image (plain red color), and tested the project, and it all worked fine :/ there is no yellow color what so ever on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your `Bitmap` is located not in `drawable-nodpi` folder and that's why it's getting scaled.

According to documentation of [Canvas.drawBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29):

> If the bitmap and canvas have different densities, this function will take care of automatically scaling the bitmap to draw at the same density as the canvas.

Comment: +1 The first time I needed this, it took me a few hours of headache to figure out that `inScaled=false` is basically useless.

Comment: Ahhh... these folders again! I had a similar problem a while ago because of them, but forgot completly. Thanks!